# Setting a default value to avoid error being prompted when using $_GET in php

Tags: php, html, get, bootstrap-modal

Quick question, when passing a value with $_GET I use isset to check if the value is set then assign the value, what is the best way to handle before a value is set?

EG client clicks a modal and a popup with information about that is popped up.

Currently I get a php error displaying on top of the page saying $_GET value is not set, which is fine, but when in production this isn't ideal.

Attached some code for an example.

```
<?php


// checks to see if the movie id is actually set in url.
if(isset($_GET['movie_id'])) {

$movieID = $_GET['movie_id'];

} else {
  echo MovieId is not set.
}


echo $movieID;

 ?>
```

Added the actual code giving me an error

```
<?php
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'**/core/init.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = (int)$id;

echo $id;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE recid = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


?>
```

**Note:** ** replaces file directory as not required.

**Error:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in 
>   **\includes\quickModal.php on line 11

Line 11 is the `$sql` line.

Comment: how you are getting this id, is it user input ?? and what you want to achieve you want to do if id is not set ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, use `isset()` function in PHP to check if the value is set:

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

```
if(isset($_GET['movie_id'])) {

$movieID = $_GET['movie_id'];

} else {
  echo MovieId is not set.
}
```

---

In your code's context, you can put the query within the if statement checking if `$_GET` is set. This will prevent the SQL statement from executing when `$_GET` is not set:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = (int)$id;
    echo $id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE recid = '$id'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

---

Also, to echo a string, you will need quotes:

```
echo "MovieId is not set.";
```

Comment: sorry of course with the echo, whats currently happening tho if movie_id isn't set it prints an error, whats the best way to avoid (handle) this on a production site?

Comment: @Jcode What error is it? PHP error or the error that you set (MovieId is not set.)?

Comment: Ill add the actual code I'm working on, a $sql command calls it as well, which I think causes an error. One sec

Comment: I'm not sure why but when the modal is called first time it gets a lot of errors and doesn't display anything. When clicking from one to another it still holds information on the previous modal. I believe this is something to do with my Require_once and includes as I changed them all and this issue occured. so seperate issue, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jcode You're welcome! You can ask a new question if you have a separate issue :)